# How to detect closed contour objects in an image and store radii and center points?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have the following picture:
[image]

I would like to detect the 7 white 'circular' paper-parts (closed contours) in Matlab and store the radii and center points. I have tried the following ways:

- Feature matching the original image (top-left) with reference image (bottom-right)
- Filter out the edges (top-right and bottom-left) and fit multiple circles to the data points
- Detecting circles in original picture (top-left) with Circular Hough

but they did not work. I am a beginner in image processing, could someone please help? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can play with [contour](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) function, by specifying either number of levels or levels directly. If you need contour coordinates, you can use the low level function [contourc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourc.html), whose output format is a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Use blob detection after adaptive binarization. Center and area are readily computed and you can estimate the radius from the area.

Comment: Could you plaase explain it in more detail, because as I said I am a beginner :)

Comment: Read on "connected components analysis".